# how to validate field already exist on form update

Tags: django, python-3.x

I add a validation on form.py to exclude the same record at the time of update  so I check the username already exist or not, but `self.instance.pk` is getting None.

I know there are also another way to do this but I want to know why self.instance.pk did not work, I will use this approach to other Forms also so I need to fix this using `self.instance.pk` 
here is my code

so could you please review the code what is I am missing and why self.instance.pk not working.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ["is_admin", "is_verified", "last_login"]

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        print(self.instance.pk)
        user_obj = CustomUser.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).get(username=username)
        if user_obj:
            raise forms.ValidationError("username already exist")
        return username
```

views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    context = {
        "form": UserForm()
    }
    user_obj = request.user
    form = UserForm(instance=user_obj)
    context["form"] = form
       if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                 form_obj = form.save()
    return render(request, "account/profile.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

when I get the request.POST data from form `form = UserForm(reqest.POST)`
I also need to add instance `instance = request.user`
so the correct code will be

```
def edit_profile(request):
    context = {
        "form": UserForm()
    }
    user_obj = request.user
    form = UserForm(instance=user_obj)
    context["form"] = form
       if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserForm(request.POST, instance = request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                 form_obj = form.save()
    return render(request, "account/profile.html", context)
```